# BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX breaks Visual Studio 2005 intellisense?

Tags: c++, atl, visual-c++-2005, wtl

I have a C++ application using WTL/ATL BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX macros for message handling. I use some macros from atlcrack.h.

When we upgraded the projects to Visual Studio 2005, intellisense acts crazy. I've tracked the behavior down to the BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX macro not behaving correctly with intellisense. However, I can not find a way to continue using BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX and Visual Studio 2005.

Do I have to rewrite all my old message handlers and stop using BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX or is there another fix?

Answer (score 4):

I've been using WTL for years and haven't come across this issue, but I also find the default Intellisense in VS2005/2008 next to useless - it stops working for no apparent reason.  If you want Intellisense to work the way God intended, I recommend you try Visual Assist X (free 30 day trial) - it *might* make your problem disappear - got to be better than changing your code to work around IDE problems?

http://www.wholetomato.com/

Comment: Visual Assist X (VSX) is generally a recommendable aid for VS, indeed. However, it too cannot cope with WTL (I'm using VS2008 with VSX build 10.5.1735.0). Working with (the powerful) WTL is sadly a real pain because of this.